# In the Xcode 4 - is there any way to make "Generic" Syntax Coloring to be the default?

Tags: xcode, syntax, highlighting

Xcode 4 uses "**None**" syntax coloring scheme as the default for unknown file types [why?!?]. Is there any way to change this and make "**Generic**" coloring scheme to be the **default** one?

I couldn't find any way to do that in the environment, after digging a bit - there's a file:
/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Standard\ file\ types.pbfilespec

Is that the right direction [ unfortunately trashing Xcode is not an option :( ]?